# Unable to login to MySQL locally after remote changes

Tags: mysql

After doing the following two things to setup remote access to my database, I'm not unable to access the database locally:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

And commented:

```
#bind-address       = 127.0.0.1
```

So now I can access remotely but not locally :/ getting the error:

> QLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the expected behavior!

If you want to allow access your database locally just uncomment

`bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

Comment: Thanks! That worked, but of course now remotely it doesn't again, there's no way to allow both I guess? Not a big deal I guess since I only needed to do a large import remotely

Comment: @kilrizzy: Sure there is a way to allow both! Bind MySQL to all IPs on all interfaces: `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`